# Illuminating a just-barely irrational polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-geometry, polygons, billiards

As has been discussed earlier on MO,<sup>1,2</sup>
recently an impressive advance was proved concerning
internally illuminating a mirrored polygon.
Here is the result:

> Let $P$ be a rational polygon.
> Then for any $x \in P$ there are at most
> finitely many points $y$ for which there is no
> geodesic trajectory between $x$ and $y$.

Here "no geodesic trajectory" means no illumination path,
using angle-of-incidence equals angle-of-reflection from the
polygon edges.
A *rational polygon* is one each of whose angles is a rational
multiple of $\pi$. So, a match lit at $x$ will leave at most
a finite number of points in $P$ dark.
[Examples were known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IlluminationProblem.html):

[image]

The result is Corollary 3 in this "Everything is illuminated" [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2016.20.1737):

> Lelievre, Samuel, Thierry Monteil, and Barak Weiss.
> "Everything is illuminated."
> *Geometry & Topology* 20, no. 3 (2016): 1737-1762.

Here finally is my question:

> ***Q***.
> Suppose $P$ has all rational vertex angles, except for two
> irrational vertex angles.
> (A polygon cannot have just one irrational angle, because the angle sum is $(n-2)\pi$.)
> Is it now true that, for any $x$,
> the entirety of $P$ is illuminated, i.e., no point is dark?

I am wondering if this is implied by their results. I do not have
sufficient grasp of their use of
the "Magic Wand Theorem"
and other translation-surface technology to understand if the answer to ***Q*** is just a
corollary, or a possibly open question.
It makes some sense to me that one irrational angle will suffice to fill
$P$ with light, because the lightray reflections become ergodic.

---

- <sup>1</sup>[Current state of Straus's illumination
  problem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/252441/6094),
- <sup>2</sup>[Using mirrors to make a non-convex polygon visible from a fixed
  interior point](https://mathoverflow.net/a/42007/6094)